# Unix paste command overwriting data

Tags: unix, paste

I'm trying to paste two files together with the `paste` command.

I'm using

```
paste file1 file2
```

to take file 1

```
E gge0001x    
D 12-30-2006    
U 1012.7    
X 36.2
```

and file2

```
gge0001y    
12-30-2006    
1014.6
35.2
```

to get file 3

```
E gge0001x gge0001y
D 12-30-2006 12-30-2006
U 1012.7 1014.6
X 36.2 35.2
```

but it ends up coming out like this

```
E gge000gge0001y    
D 12-30-12-30-2006    
U 1012.71014.6    
X 36.2 35.2
```

which is all jumbled up and overlapped.

How do I keep them apart? Shouldn't `paste` use a tab between columns/fields?

Comment: Guessing that one or both files were created or passed thru MS Windows environment. In any case, check with `cat -vet f1` and if you see `^M$` at the end of lines, do `dos2unix f1 f2 ....` (as many files as you like), to remove `\r` chars (same as `^M` (don't ask ;-/) )  before std unix line-ending char `\n`. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, there's the ^m$ at the end of the line. dos2unix works to make them pasteable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Shelter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509471/unix-paste-command-overwriting-data/36511025#comment60625803_36509471) pointed out, your file is having `^M` characters.

You can replace `^M` characters using

```
tr -d '\r' < file3 > final.txt
```

or

```
dos2unix file3 final.txt
```

or

```
sed 's/^M//g' <file3 >final.txt
```

Comment: I was able to use the `dos2unix` command just fine. Didn't try `tr` or `sed` though.